# How to center text and math in a minipage?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, minipage

My naive approach to center text in a `minipage` using `\centering` is clearly not working:

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{3cm}
\centering
    ~\newline
    X\newline
    XXX\newline
    XXXXX\newline
    $XXXXXXX$\newline
    X
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: or replace `newline` with   `\\ `.

Comment: BTW, you can use display math (e.g. \begin{equation}...) in a minipage and they will be centered without \centering.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In "normal" text `\newline` and `\\` are basically the same. However, `\centering` changes that:

```
\def\centering{%
  \let\\\@centercr
  \rightskip\@flushglue\leftskip\@flushglue
  \parindent\z@\parfillskip\z@skip}
```

so within a `minipage` with `\centering`, `\newline` still has its original definition, while `\\` is now `\@centercr`. After a couple of expansions (which I omit) in the end you'll get that

- `\newline` is essentially `\unskip\relax{\relax\relax}\nobreak\hfil\break`,
- `\\` is essentially `\unskip\par\addvspace{-\parskip}\ignorespaces`.

This means that `\newline` still has the "normal text definition" with `\hfil`, which is supposed to fill the rest of the line. Perfectly reasonable in justified text, but wrong in centred text, because it adds *additional*  glue on the right.

Long story short: use `\\`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\fbox{\begin{minipage}{3cm}
\centering
    X\newline
    XXX\newline
    XXXXX\newline
    $XXXXXXX$\newline
    X
\end{minipage}}
\fbox{\begin{minipage}{3cm}
\centering
    X\\
    XXX\\
    XXXXX\\
    $XXXXXXX$\\
    X
\end{minipage}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this very instructive answer. Wouldn't it make sense for `minipage` then to redefine `\newline` as well?

Comment: @bers Uh, you should ask someone from the team about that, but I rather think not. (BTW this is about `\centering`, not `minipage`.) It's the same in `tabular`s and similar: ``\\`` is redefined to do something specific to the current environment, but one should have a "backup" of the standard behaviour.

Comment: Of course, `\centering` :) Agreed - having both `\\` and `\newline` (doing different things) can be very helpful in a `tabular`. Thanks!